# How to implement pipe under Linux?

Tags: linux

I would like my code to handle the output coming from pipe.

for example, ls -l | mycode

how to achieve this under Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read from stdin, such as with scanf().

Answer (score 2):

The pipe in Linux/Unix will transfer the output of the first program to the standard input of the second. How you access the standard input will depend on what language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When you type "ls -l | mycode" into the shell, it is the shell program itself (e.g. `bash`, `zsh`) that does all the trickery with pipes.  It simply provides the output from `ls -l` to `mycode` on standard input.  Similarly, anything you write on standard output or error can be redirected or piped by the shell to some other process or file.  Exactly how to read and write to those files depends on the language.